# Why are we suddenly getting 403 on graph calls to list a team's channels?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We do run the GET call: 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/711fc163-0408-4649-9a30-af65a5d30b52/channels

It used to return the channels just fine, but this week it suddenly starting failing with this error:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "AccessDenied",
    "message": "Failed to execute Skype backend request GetThreadsS2SRequest.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "226d8e17-fa0f-4c42-8139-4776e198a3b2",
      "date": "2019-08-26T19:25:10"
    }
  }
}

We see that the problem is happening for different teams and across different tenants. This is critical!

Comment: Thank you for reporting this issue. This appears to be an issue with the service API. We are looking into it. Could you please try again and let us know if you are still facing this issue.

Comment: It works again now :) @Trinetra-MSFT

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this issue. There was an issue going on with List Channel Graph API which has been fixed now.

Comment: This is not seems tobe fixed. I raised similar issue here.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/844861/bug-call-to-channels-are-failing.html