# Failed to execute Skype backend request GetThreadS2SRequest

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Calling `GET` https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/5732849c-7b33-433c-b9aa-7d80f0274034/channels results in 403 (Forbidden) error with the body:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "Failed to execute Skype backend request GetThreadS2SRequest.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-12-02T20:52:22",
            "request-id": "dbe941bd-7e8e-4756-a197-d1b7c1ce9c57",
            "client-request-id": "dbe941bd-7e8e-4756-a197-d1b7c1ce9c57"
        }
    }
}
```

This is a similar issue as reported in [Why are we suddenly getting 403 on graph calls to list a team's channels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57663906/why-are-we-suddenly-getting-403-on-graph-calls-to-list-a-teams-channels)

As I understand from a number of forums this issue occurs from time to time. At this moment I'm waiting for a week for this issue to be resolved, but I've never succeeded in getting the list of channels yet. All permissions are granted and it really looks like an internal issue of Graph API and my question is what are the further directions for the users facing this issue? Is there a resource where users can track the status of this issue? Because every related thread I found is closed but the issue still occurs.

Comment: 403 refer to the permission issue. Could you please check the required permissions as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)?

Comment: Make sure you have enough permissions, roles require to perform this above Graph API call. You can check the token using https://jwt.ms, see the scope/permission/roles as well

Comment: I miss ChannelSettings.Read.Group and ChannelSettings.ReadWrite.Group permissions. Added them to app Manifest and got this error: "A value without a type name was found and no expected type is available. When the model is specified, each value in the payload must have a type which can be either specified in the payload, explicitly by the caller or implicitly inferred from the parent value".
I used the description from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/rsc/resource-specific-consent#configure-group-owner-consent-settings-in-the-azure-ad-portal

Comment: I've change manifest by adding webApplicationInfo key that looks like this:
"webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "my-app-id",
    "resource": "https://RscBasedStoreApp",
    "applicationPermissions": [
      "ChannelSettings.Read.Group",
      "ChannelSettings.ReadWrite.Group"
    ]
  }

But this method doesn't work and I cant find another method to add those two permissions.

Comment: You need to add the permissions in the azure where you have registered the application.

Comment: does the above helped?

Comment: @vadimPashaev, did the above thing helped?

Comment: No. I can't find where to add "ChannelSettings.ReadWrite.Group" permission in azure where I registered the app. I'm using Postman to make API calls and the only place where I can enable ChannelSettings.ReadWrite.Group permission is Teams App, but I don't use one.

Comment: You will find the permissions under application permission. Could you please try adding the required permission?

Comment: @VadimPashaev- Could you please confirm if your issue is resolved? Also, could you please try calling same for V1 endpoint instead of beta and check?